# Inserting spaces between a 5 digit number

Tags: c, space, digits

I have started an intro to programming course that uses the C language and we have an assignment to make a program that takes a 5 digit number from the user such as `12345` and it prints it out as `1 2 3 4 5`.

I tried to google around for help but all the answers given used code way too complicated for my understanding considering the course just started and we have only learned `printf` and `scanf`, `if` and `switch` statements and `while` and `for` loops.

I tried putting all the numbers given into separate `int` variables which made the program stop and then tried to put them into chars but the testing program said it was wrong since we are supposed to use `int`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

**EDIT:**

What I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1,
        num2,
        num3,
        num4,
        num5;

    printf("Give 5 digit number > ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &num5);

    printf("Seperated number is %d %d %d %d %d", num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    return (0);
}
```

Also tried that code but with `char` variable type but that wasn't allowed it has to be `int`.

The testing program gives an expected output which for `00001` is `Given number 1 seperated is 0 0 0 0 1` or for `-12321` is `Given number -12321 seperated is -1 -2 -3 -2 -1`

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried. Then we can help.

Comment: Is it okay to only print the spaces as you print the number? So you don't need to store the number with spaces inside the running program?

Comment: If this were a maths problem how would you extract the digits from a number on a piece of paper? That is, what algorithm can you think of to extract each digit?

Comment: It really depends on how you are "taking" the input from the user.  If you are reading a string, then you probably should never convert it to an int at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can read user input into a char array using scanf.
2. Then using for loop you can loop through each char (1,2,3,4,5)
3. Use printf in the loop to print from array and a space. `printf("%c ", input_from_user[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the point here is understanding how C stores things. You're reading in characters (that is a set of 8-byte values that are commonly displayed as letters) and converting each one to an integer (commonly a 32-bit value that stores a number)

So you want to read the input using scanf to get a character string of your 5 digits, then use a for loop to go over each one, reading a single character from the string and converting it into an integer variable. then printf that variable plus a space, and move on to repeat the next digit.

If you read the digits in one by one then its even easier as you only need the for loop to read, convert, and print each digit as its read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the purpose of this exercise.  If you are learning C, the last function you should learn is `scanf`.  It boggles the mind that so many people teach it early.  Try very hard not to use scanf at all until you understand the language well enough to realize that you probably never need it.  That said, I suppose the point of the exercise is to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
        unsigned num;
        char buf[6];
        printf("Give 5 digit number > ");
        if( scanf("%u", &num) != 1 || num > 99999 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Separated number is");
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", num);
        for( int i = 0; buf[i]; i++ ) {
                printf(" %c", buf[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux good point.  The value returned by snprintf can be larger than the size of the buffer (not true in this case, since we've already validated the number), so I've edited to check for null.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, you would be given a number of 5 digits and then you have to print the digits of that number as well.

So, in your program, you have taken five digits individually as input, to me it seems wrong. I am giving my solution below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num,idx=0,i=0;
    int arr[5]; // for storing the five digits;
    scanf("%d",&num);


     
    while(num){   //loop will terminate when the num = 0
       int digit = num%10;
       num = num/10;
       arr[idx] = digit;
       idx++;
    }

   //Printing from the last, as the digit are stored in reverse order.
    for(int i=4;i>=0;i--){      
       printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `int arr[5] = { 0 };` to avoid printing uninitialized `arr[]`.

Comment: No checking.  Fails for 6 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Although likely beyond OP's stage, code can use recursion to print the value from most significant to least.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_digit(int n, int depth) {
  if (depth > 1) print_digit(n/10, depth - 1);  // print "left" digits first
  printf(" %d", n%10);
}

void print_5(int n) {
  // To do: checking for correct spelling
  printf("Given number %d seperated", n);  // or separated
  print_digit(n, 5);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  print_5(1);
  print_5(-12321);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Given number 1 seperated 0 0 0 0 1
Given number -12321 seperated -1 -2 -3 -2 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your approach by limiting the number of bytes you read for each number:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

    printf("Give 5 digit number > ");
    if (scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &num1, &num2,&num3, &num4, &num5) == 5) {
        printf("Separated number is %d %d %d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that this is probably not what you are expected to do. You should instead read a single number and decompose it into its five digits:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;

    printf("Give 5 digit number > ");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num >= 10000 && num <= 99999) {
        printf("Separated number is %d %d %d %d %d\n", 
               num / 10000, num / 1000 % 10, num / 100 % 10, num / 10 % 10, num % 10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%1d"` likely has trouble with negative numbers which are at least 2 characters.

Comment: I suspect the 2nd way is what is sought.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the first solution also accepts leading blanks such as `1 2 3 4 5` which is incorrect. The leading blanks are not counted toward the width indicator. A sign, `+` or `-`, should indeed cause conversion failure because the 1 byte sequence does not have the expected form for a `%d` conversion.